# ValidationTokens Missing in Notification received from Microsoft Graph Webhook

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using Microsoft Graph (beta) Webhooks to get notified about presence changes in Microsoft Teams and have currently an issue at our customer.
When we receive the presence change notification from the Graph API it does not contain the `validationTokens` property, thus the validation and subsequent processing fails.
Our code is similar to the [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample/blob/main/src/GraphWebhooks-Core/Controllers/NotificationController.cs) provided by Microsoft.

The (simplified/shortened) content of the received request at the customer looks like the following:

```json
{
   "value": [
      {
         "subscriptionId": "...",
         "clientState": "...",
         "changeType": "updated",
         "resource": "communications/presences?$filter=id+in+(...)",
         "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2021-04-22T02:06:56.2872368-07:00",
         "resourceData": {
            "@odata.id": "communications/presences?$filter=id+in+(...)",
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.presence",
            "id": "..."
         },
         "tenantId": "...",
         "encryptedContent": {
            "data": "...",
            "dataSignature": "...",
            "dataKey": "...",
            "encryptionCertificateId": "3",
            "encryptionCertificateThumbprint": "..."
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Compared to our lab the request body is missing the `validationTokens` property:

```json
{
   "value": [
      {
         "subscriptionId": "...",
         "clientState": "...",
         "changeType": "updated",
         "resource": "communications/presences?$filter=id+in+(...)",
         "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2021-04-26T00:07:08.9251516-07:00",
         "resourceData": {
            "@odata.id": "communications/presences?$filter=id+in+(...)",
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.presence",
            "id": "..."
         },
         "tenantId": "...",
         "encryptedContent": {
            "data": "...",
            "dataSignature": "...",
            "dataKey": "...",
            "encryptionCertificateId": "3",
            "encryptionCertificateThumbprint": "..."
         }
      }
   ],
   "validationTokens": [
      "..."
   ]
}
```

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/changenotificationcollection?view=graph-rest-1.0), `validationTokens` are only provided for change notifications with resource data - which is the case here, so we guess the `validationTokens` should be present?

Any hints are welcome.

**Edit**
Here is a shortened code snipped used to deserialize the request body/handle the notification request:

```vb
      <HttpPost("/Notification/{connectorId}/{apiLinkId}")>
      Public Async Function Listen(connectorId As Guid, apiLinkId As Guid, <FromQuery> Optional validationToken As String = Nothing) As Task(Of IActionResult)
         If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken) Then
            ' Validate the new subscription by sending the token back to Microsoft Graph.
            ' This response is required for each subscription.
            Return Content(WebUtility.HtmlEncode(validationToken))
         End If

         Try
            ' Parse the received notifications.
            Dim options As New JsonSerializerOptions With {.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = True}
            options.Converters.Add(New JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase))

            Dim plainNotifications As New Dictionary(Of String, ChangeNotification)()
            Dim notificationCollection = Await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(Of ChangeNotificationCollection)(Request.Body, options)
            notificationCollection.Value _
               .Where(Function(x) x.EncryptedContent Is Nothing) _
               .ForEach(Sub(notification)
                           Dim subscription = Stores.TeamsPresenceSubscriptionStore.Instance.GetValueOrDefault(notification.SubscriptionId.Value)

                           ' Verify the current client state matches the one that was sent.
                           If subscription Is Nothing OrElse notification.ClientState <> subscription.SecretClientState Then
                              Log.msg(Category.TEAMS, "Error: Failed to verify notification")
                              Return
                           End If

                           ' Just keep the latest notification for each resource. No point pulling data more than once.
                           plainNotifications(notification.Resource) = notification
                        End Sub)

            If plainNotifications.Count > 0 Then
               ' Query for the changed messages
               GetChangedMessages(plainNotifications.Values)
            End If

            If notificationCollection.ValidationTokens IsNot Nothing AndAlso notificationCollection.ValidationTokens.Any() Then
               ' -> notificationCollection.ValidationTokens is not set at the customer
            End If

         Catch ex As Exception
            ' Still return a 202 so the service doesn't resend the notification.
         End Try
         Return Accepted()
      End Function
```

The code to create the subscription is

```vb
         Subscription = graphApi.Client.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(New Subscription() With
            {
               .Resource = $"/communications/presences?$filter=id in ({String.Join(",", userIds.Select(Function(id) $"'{id}'"))})",
               .ChangeType = "updated",
               .NotificationUrl = $"{publicNotificationEndpoint}/Notification/{connectorid}/{Me.GraphApi.Link.Id}",
               .LifecycleNotificationUrl = $"{publicNotificationEndpoint}/LifecycleNotification/{connectorid}/{Me.GraphApi.Link.Id}",
               .ClientState = SecretClientState,
               .ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(MAX_SUBSCRIPTION_LIFETIME),
               .EncryptionCertificate = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptionCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert)),
               .EncryptionCertificateId = encryptionCertificate.Version.ToString(),
               .IncludeResourceData = True
            }).Result
```

Comment: Just to isolate the issue you can try repro the issue using Graph Explorer or POSTMAN to see if you see different result.

Comment: Hi @hypetsch, could you please share the piece of code that you are using to get validationTokens.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT - as requested I added the (simplified) code above, but as mentioned validationTokens are not part of the JSON content we receive in the notification. The JSON I added in the question is actually the formatted/shortened content captured via Wireshark.
Anyways I marked the position where .validationTokens property is not set.

Comment: Hi @hypetsch, are you still facing the issue

Comment: We have meanwhile implemented a workaround (and ignore the validation tokens).
I will ask our service department to contact the customer and ask if they can try it.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT, we got feedback from our customer: it is still not working without the workaround (which is ignoring the validation tokens)

Comment: Hi @hypetsch, we will update you soon.

Comment: Hi @hypetsch, our team is debugging you code, will post the answer by today eod

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT, the customer has asked whether you have any news. The workaround is still in place so we can currently not confirm, that the validationTokens property are still missing. If you require additional information (e.g. tenant related data, the actually used notification URL, current network trace...), let us know - we could ask the customer if it is ok to provide such information directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for subscribing to the presence API using the Change Notification API, We have developed samples in csharp and node js which have the capability to notify user when presence is updated, You can take a look at following github sample code repo [graph-change-notification](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-change-notification) for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the issue in our case is only that the "validationTokens" in the received notification are missing (only at a specific customer, while it is working fine for others) - and the way we understand the docs, they should be there in case of presence resources
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/changenotificationcollection?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: ...received presence data is fine (also at this customer) - so our workaround was to process data without validating the received request first.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of a late reply but the validationToken will only send to the webhook at the time of Subscription creation, after that Microsoft start sending the chang notifications and there won't be any validationToken send with the change notification. This is done just to ensure that the Notification endpoint is valid/active.

[Notification endpoint validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAEDD.png)

SS taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks